# Find a generator of $\mathbb{F}_{7}^*$, the multiplicative group of non-zero elements of $\mathbb{F}_7$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Find a generator of $\mathbb{F}_{7}^*$, the multiplicative group of non-zero elements of $\mathbb{F}_7$

Comment: What did you try? I think you are inexperience with this site, but it is recommended that you include your effort when you're asking a question.

Comment: Which elements did you actually try? There are really not that many different ones.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $2^3\equiv1$, $3^2\equiv2$ (modulo $7$).

Comment: answer is 3 or 5. can you tell how its came

Comment: @sundaresanP If the order of $2$ is three and $3^2=2$, what's the order of $3$? And what's $3^{-1}$? How many elements are generators in a cyclic group of order $6$?

Comment: order of 3 is 6 and $3^{-1}$ is 5. there are 3 elements are generators in a cyclic group of order 6 i.e {1,3,$3^{-1}=5}

Comment: @sundaresanP It follows from what I hinted at that $3^6=1$, but no lower power is $1$. Hence the order of $3$ is $6$.  Since $3^{-1}=5$, also $5$ has order $6$. A cyclic group of order $6$ has just two generators.

Comment: then what else you want from your first comment

Comment: @sundaresanP $1$ is not a generator.

Answer (score 1):

The generators are 3 or 5 (under modulo 7)
<3>={3,3^2,3^3,3^4,3^5,3^6}={3,2,6,4,5,1}
<5>={5,5^2,5^3,5^4,5^5,5^6}={5,4,6,2,3,1}